# Where on my resume should I include a membership in a club that is related to my profession?

Tags: resume

- Member of Dreamland Computer science society.

Should I write the above line under *Hobbies* section in my resume or under the *Awards and Honors* section?

Comment: Google can't find a "Dreamland Computer science society", so it's probably not that important => Hobby, if at all.

Comment: I've heard HR people only spend 6 seconds on a resume, do you think they'll google it?

Comment: To rephrase: If it's nomething nobody heard of, it's not a honor. For that, it needs to be something well-known, with an very good reputation, not open to everyone, (etc.) ... "Nobel prize" yes, "price for being the best in elementary school math in somewhereXY" no. You get the idea.

Comment: If they spend only 6 seconds on the initial screening, they will say "never heard of it, and 'member' is a weak qualification at best" and it won't help you. If you get past that stage, someone *is* likely to look it up and it may hurt you if they think you're making something up. Hobby at most, quite possibly better not to mention at all.

Comment: @deviantfan hope you are making a joke. ofc azam used a fictional organization.

Comment: @Mindwin Since OP replied to ask whether HR would figure that out instead of mentioning that he made it up for this question I'm not so sure he doesn't intend to use a fictional organization in his actual resume...

Answer (score 4):

***Everything*** on a resume should be geared towards why you deserve the job you are applying for.

The ***Hobbies*** section on a resume is something they get kids leaving school to write in because most wouldn't have much else beyond projected/actual grades. It is not something I'd expect on the resume of anyone who isn't leaving school - to most hiring managers a *hobby* is something like model-making.

On the other hand - if there is some aspect of being a member of a society or non-professional organisation that can help with exemplifying your skills, then include it under the a section title ***Other interests***. If you were the president or committee member for a society, what did you do to help the society.

For example, I was a Scout Commissioner for a time in my twenties - I've included that in *Other interests* as I was able to provide examples of leadership (I was responsible for running a programme for multiple units/troops and assisting/training the adult leaders in each troop), organisation (organising expeditions, setting up air rifle range with instructor and Scout training programmes for the region, etc).

What I don't include is being a member of the University Mountaineering Club, because I just turned up and hiked.

So, if you're organising events with this computer society, or managing membership, then include it. If you're just turning up to play LAN games with a few other gamers, then I wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 3):

If this was something that contributed to your professional skills I would include it under a heading of "PROFESSIONAL AFFILIATIONS".  However this post is the only thing that comes up when you search for "Dreamland Computer science society" so I am guessing that it will not add anything useful to your resume.

Answer (score 3):

The only time I advise bothering with memberships are if they are prestigious and exclusive or if they are licensing related.

For prestigious and exclusive think of things like government advisory boards or military veterans associations.

Including membership in your local association of professional engineers or your local association of realtors would definitely add value if you are looking for jobs in these fields.

Answer (score 0):

"Member" counts for very little. What did you actually do that demonstrates leadership, teaching skills, or anything else that might be useful to an employer?